# How to iterate and group through dictionary in python

Tags: python, api, dictionary

I am fighting with the query as I have to count What are the total CO2 emissions by each Airline?

I have managed to get all the data to a dictionary which looks like

```
Flight Number is 2HX and the airline is IT and the aircraft is E195 going from EDDF to LIMF
Flight distance is 542.93 km
Flight CO2 emissions is 16.87 kg

Flight Number is 8031 and the airline is ES and the aircraft is B752 going from LEBL to EDDP
Flight distance is 1365.97 km
Flight CO2 emissions is 31.07 kg

Flight Number is 39DV and the airline is ES and the aircraft is A320 going from LEPA to LEMD
Flight distance is 546.33 km
Flight CO2 emissions is 16.92 kg
```

All calculations are done by all of the flights but I would like to group them based on the AIRLINE, thus increasing the total results for them and printing them accordingly.

Any ideas how I could start it?

JSON file loaded looks like this

```
[{"hex": "150694", "reg_number": "RA-67220", "flag": "RU", "lat": 51.633911, "lng": 50.050518, "alt": 11582, "dir": 290, "speed": 761, "v_speed": 0.3, "squawk": "0507", "flight_number": "9004", "flight_icao": "TUL9004", "dep_icao": "VIDP", "dep_iata": "DEL", "airline_icao": "PLG", "aircraft_icao": "CRJ2", "updated": 1675528289, "status": "en-route"}, {"hex": "152038", "reg_number": "RA-73784", "flag": "RU", "lat": 43.352108, "lng": 35.634342, "alt": 11277, "dir": 4, "speed": 881, "v_speed": 0, "squawk": "7313", "flight_number": "427", "flight_icao": "AFL427", "flight_iata": "SU427", "dep_icao": "HESH", "dep_iata": "SSH", "arr_icao": "UUEE", "arr_iata": "SVO", "airline_icao": "AFL", "airline_iata": "SU", "aircraft_icao": "A333", "updated": 1675528054, "status": "en-route"}, {"hex": "152052", "reg_number": "RA-73810", "flag": "RU", "lat": 59.739784, "lng": 85.652138, "alt": 9745, "dir": 89, "speed": 801, "v_speed": 0, "squawk": "5521", "flight_number": "173", "flight_icao": "SVR173", "flight_iata": "U6173", "dep_icao": "USSS", "dep_iata": "SVX", "arr_icao": "UHHH", "arr_iata": "KHV", "airline_icao": "SVR", "airline_iata": "U6", "aircraft_icao": "A319", "updated": 1675528294, "status": "en-route"}
```

Basically function for listing flights look like this, but I would like to group them by airlines and add value of co2 emissions to each of individual results

```
def list_all_flights(self):
    #List all flights
    total_result = 0 
    for i in self.flights_list.read_data_file(): # json.file
        if(i.get('dep_icao') and i.get('arr_icao')):
                print(f"Flight Number is {i['flight_number']} and the airline is {i['flag']} and the aircraft is {i['aircraft_icao']} going from {i['dep_icao']} to {i['arr_icao']}");
```

I have managed to count all encounters of different airline  inside new dictionary and it works

```
if 'flag' in i:
                temp[i['flag']] = temp.get(i['flag'], 0) + 1'
```

Now I would like to add the result for co2 emissions as a total for an airline.

Comment: _I have managed to get all the data to a dictionary which looks like_ - This is not a dictionary

Comment: you are right they are coming from json file that I could get attributes like dictionary i.get('flag') for the airline I was hoping if there is a way to group the values in total for each one of the airline.

Comment: Please, post [mre] of your code, incl. sample JSON and expected output

Comment: I am sorry I am new in this, I have added some entries how json looks like.

Comment: I have managed to count all encounters of different airline  inside new dictionary and it works
'''
               if 'flag' in i:
                    temp[i['flag']] = temp.get(i['flag'], 0) + 1'
'''

Answer (score 0):

By making use of Pandas module (you can install via `pip install pandas`) I made this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("data.json")
result = {a_iata:[] for a_iata in df.airline_iata.unique()}
for a_iata in result:
    result[a_iata] = df.loc[df.airline_iata == a_iata]
```

Where `data.json` is the data that you have provided. The code essentially filtrates every entry by its `airline_iata` value and stores them into individual DataFrames. You can see the data by using `result['AIRLINE_CODE']` and it will return the DataFrame.

When you are constructing your message, you can use something like this:

```
temp_df = result['AIRLINE_CODE']
message = f"Flight reg number is {temp_df.reg_number}..."
```

You can fill the message out however you like.